# Difference Between Datasets

Tags: machine-learning, data-analysis

Here is the problem statement:

I have 2 datasets from different years(2013 dataset and 2014 dataset), the data is multivariate with each dataset containing 38 attributes, I want to find out any difference/delta that might have occured in between two datasets in these consecutive years, this difference should be a numerical value.

So far I have applied following techniques:

1)ANOVA (This tells me that difference is there but it doesn't tell me how much the difference is)

2)Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney U test (Same problem as ANOVA)

3)Finding the Mean Square Error between the mean of the datasets.

Questions:

1) Is their any other method/test that can be applied which would give me a numerical value of the difference between datasets?

2) If I label the 2013 dataset as "1" and 2014 dataset as "2" then can the weight's of  neural network trained to classify these dataset be used to somehow find the difference between datasets?

Note: Due to confidentiality agreement I cannot share the data here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - Calculate difference between similar datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907523/r-calculate-difference-between-similar-datasets)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you have found an answer or not.

Have you tried using RMSE? You can create a score for every column of a dataset and then combine them to get an average score for the whole data.

It's not a perfect method but it should give a scale of difference when comparing multiple dataset to eachother.

If you did find a better answer than what I suggested, please so let me know as I would be interested in it.

All the best.

Comment: It's also a good idea to state whether you need to work with a dataset or whether you can work with a regression. Some methods might not be suitable as a regression and will only work with the entire dataset.