# R - Calculate difference (similarity measure) between similar datasets

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-analysis, missing-data, data-manipulation

I have seen many questions that touch on this topic but haven't yet found an answer. If I have missed a question that does answer this question, please do mark this and point us to the question.

Scenario: We have a benchmark dataset, we have imputation methods, we systematically delete values from the benchmark and use two different imputation methods. Thus we have a benchmark, imputedData1 and imputedData2.

Question: Is there a function that can produce a number that represents the difference between the benchmark and imputedData1 or/and the difference between the benchmark and imputedData2. Ie function(benchmark, imputedData1) = 3.3 and function(benchmark, imputedData2) = 2.8

Note: Datasets are numerical, datasets are the same size, method should work at the data level if possible (ie not creating a regression and comparing regressions - unless it can work with ANY numerical dataset).

Reproducible datasets, they have only been changed in the first row:

benchmark:

```
> head(mtcars,n=10)
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
```

imputedData1:

```
> head(mtcars,n=10)
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         22.0   4 108.0 100 3.90 2.200 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
```

imputedData2:

```
> head(mtcars,n=10)
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         18.0   6 112.0 105 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  0    3    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
```

I have tried to use RMSE (root mean squared error) but it didn't work very well so I am trying to find other ways to tackle this problem.

Comment: Since your variables have very different ranges, I would standardize (z-transform) them before running any comparisons: `apply(df, 2, scale)`. Then your RMSE approach might work better.

Comment: That's a very good idea. I'm a little embarrassed that I didn't consider it. Many thanks!

Comment: it may work but if the second data set is twice the first exactly the comparison will give zero. I think the data should be centered and reduced according to the benchmark's mean and sd (for benchmark AND imputedData), and then apply RMSE. Of course it depends what OP calls a "difference"

Comment: Another good point, many thanks! As I mention is a comment on the first answer, how come the word "difference" creates confusion or ambiguity?

Comment: Yes, Moody_Mudskipper is of course right. Standardize all datasets according to the benchmark.

Comment: Well if it's not defined it's ambiguous :). Difference is usually defined as the result of a simple substraction, and it's not what you want here. for some purposes a dataset exactly twice bigger can be considered "the same"

Comment: Haha unfortunately that logic doesn't hold up in court! :) I dissagree with the simple subtraction, for example the difference between me and my hypothetical twin sister is not a simple subtraction but we would quantify it. I began calling it a distance rather than a difference (my background is in pure maths) but that just confused my peers.

Comment: @abdnChap I actually did provided both a distance and a difference measure in my answer. The other answers elaborated based on the comments as well. Can we conclude the problem as solved? (might want to mark one that answers your question the best as the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also check out package `ftsa`. It has about [20 error measures](https://rdrr.io/cran/ftsa/man/error.html) that can be calculated. In your case, a scaled error would make sense as the units differ from column to column.

```
library(ftsa)
error(forecast=unlist(imputedData1),true=unlist(bench), 
          insampletrue = unlist(bench), method = "mase")
[1] 0.035136

error(forecast=unlist(imputedData2),true=unlist(bench), 
          insampletrue = unlist(bench), method = "mase")
[1] 0.031151
```

**data**

```
bench <- read.table(text='mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4',header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

imputedData1 <- read.table(text='mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
22.0   4 108.0 100 3.90 2.200 16.46  0  1    4    4
21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4',header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

imputedData2 <- read.table(text='mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
18.0   6 112.0 105 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  0    3    4
21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4',header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to calculate a norm of their difference and prefer the imputation method that minimises this value.  There are different matrix norms for different purposes.  I'll point you to the wikipedia as a starting point - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm.

In the absence of any specifics about your data I can't really say which you should choose but one method could be to create your own index that averages across different matrix norms and select the imputation method that minimizes this average.  Or you could just eyeball them and with any luck one of the methods is a clear winner across most or all matrix norms.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have considered this but I trying to create a system that is as autonomous as possible so if we need to make choices according to the dataset and the system can't make that choice, it's no good. I will look into it some more to make sure though. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

A simple implementation of what was discussed in the comments that gives a result with same order of magnitude as P Lapointe's answer, just FYI.

```
library(magrittr)
center_and_reduce_df <- function(df,bm){
  centered <- mapply('-',df,sapply(bm,mean)) %>% as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
  reduced <- mapply('/',centered,sapply(bm,sd)) %>% as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
}
mean((center_and_reduce_df(id1,bm) - center_and_reduce_df(bm,bm))^2) # 0.03083166
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I have some testing to carry out!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by "difference", but if you just want to know how much each cell differs from each cell on average (given the matrices are of the same shape and have indentical cols/rows), you could do absolute difference, or use Euclidean distance, or Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance - depending again on what you mean by "difference".

```
abs(head(mtcars) - (head(mtcars)*0.5)) # differences by cell
mean( as.matrix(abs(head(mtcars) - (head(mtcars)*0.5)))) # mean abs difference
dist( t(data.frame(as.vector(as.matrix(head(mtcars))), (as.vector(as.matrix(head(mtcars)*0.5)))))) # Euclidean; remove t() to see element by element
ks.test( as.vector(as.matrix(head(mtcars))), (as.vector(as.matrix(head(mtcars)*0.5))))$statistic  # K-S
```

Comment: I will deffo give this a try, thanks for your input! Just out of interest, out of all the similar types of questions I have read to find an answer, there is always comments which struggle with the concept of "difference". Wondering why you're not sure what I mean, is it that there are different types of "difference"? All the best.

Comment: @abdnChap well I just gave you 3 different measures that could all be called difference of sorts, and 2 other answers provided further interpretations...